# Lower bound $L_{1}$-metric with $L_{2}$-metric for bounded pdfs, on common support

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, it.information-theory

### Setup

To clarify, let constants $0 < a < b < \infty$, and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Further let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ be a fixed compact support. We then define the space of bounded (probability) densities on $B$, as follows:

$$
\mathcal{F}_{B}^{[a, b]} := \left\{f \colon B \to [a, b] \mid \int_{B}{f} d\mu = 1, \text{$f$ measurable} \right\}
$$

Where $\mu$ is taken to be a normalizing (prob) measure. We can then define the $L_{1}$- metric, and $L_{2}$-metric on $\mathcal{F}_{B}^{[a, b]}$, as follows:

\begin{aligned}
&\|f-g\|_1=\int|f-g| d \mu \\
&\|f-g\|_2^2=\int(f-g)^2 d \mu
\end{aligned}

### Question

The [lecture notes](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Eyw562/teaching/598/lec17.pdf) claim *without proof* (on top of page 4) that

\begin{equation}
\|f-g\|_1^2 \gtrsim\|f-g\|_2^2,
\end{equation}
where $\gtrsim$ means greater than or equal to, ignoring universal constants (which may depend on $a, b, B$).

This claim seems rather remarkable. Could anyone please prove this, if it is true? Or provide a suitable counterexample if it is false?

If it is true, what are the constants in the inequality (in terms of $a, b, B$)?

### Additional Comments

If this inequality is true, then I believe it would imply a [reverse Pinsker inequality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.07118.pdf) on $\mathcal{F}_{B}^{[a, b]}$ (see equation (10)), which is non-trivial since $B$ here is assumed to be compact, not just finite.

**Aside:** Although this has been [asked elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494978/l-1-distance-is-bigger-up-to-constants-than-l-2-distance-for-bounded-pdfs), the original specification there was slightly different and the counterexample given there does not apply (since they did not assume a *common* support set $B$). Moreover, the original math.SE question is now quite old and inactive. Since this is a research related question with no well citable proof, I believe it is fair to post here on math.overflow to settle the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. If (let's say) $f-g=1$ on a set of measure $\epsilon$ and $|f-g|\simeq \epsilon$ otherwise (and note that we can still normalize them both), then $\|f-g\|_1^2\simeq \epsilon^2$, $\|f-g\|_2^2\simeq\epsilon$.

For a concrete example, you can take $\mu$ as Lebesgue measure on $B=[0,1]$ and then
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 & x<\epsilon \\ \frac{1-2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} & x>\epsilon \end{cases} , \quad g(x)=1 .
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful response. A couple of quick follow-up clarifications **(1)** I believe you specifically require $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ in your counterexample. This should ensure that the density integrates to 1, is that correct? **(2)** Is there any way to add more restrictions to the density space $\mathcal{F}_{B}^{[a, b]}$ make this inequality go through?

Comment: (1) Yes, $0<\epsilon<1$ is fine, but really the point is that $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, so we only need values close to zero. (2) The inequality seems unexpected (as you already pointed out in your question), so I don't think there's a natural situation where you have it anyway.

Comment: Thank you again, appreciate your clarifications.